# Is the Gas Fee refunded if the transaction fails?

Tags: solidity, ethereum-wallet-dapp, dapp-development

I'm confusing the rule of paying gas fee when caller makes a transaction.

The gas fee is needed when the transaction is made and I know that the require() is the guard function that returns all the gas fee to the caller.

Is the gas fee paid after all operations in the function in the smart contract?

Then, if the require() function is placed at the start of the function and the codes aren't operated at all, does that mean no gas fee is needed?

And what if the value in that require() statement is false condition and the transaction therefore fails?

Is the gas fee 100% refunded to the caller or does the caller have to pay a remaining gas fee after some operations in the function worked?

Can the caller be refunded all gas?

```
function burn(uint256 _value) public returns (bool success) {
    require(balances[msg.sender] >= _value);
    balances[msg.sender] = balances[msg.sender].sub(_value);
    totalSupply = totalSupply.sub(_value);
    Burn(msg.sender, _value);
    return true;
}
```

If the gas fee has to be paid after the code has been executed, what happens if caller(msg.sender) can not pay the gas fee because caller's account has no balance after the require () conditional pass?

I doubt that I know right.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The gas has to be supplied with the signed transaction. The contract function cannot be called unless gas is supplied. There is no way to overdraw the account. It's like the fuel in your car. You need some to get started, and if there is enough, you will make it to your destination. If there is not enough, everything stops.

Source code is compiled into assembly code and any time something is happening, OPCODES are being used. Gas is charged for the OPCODES, as it's used, so even if the first line is a `require()` and it's `false`, it still took a lot of OPCODES to unpack the transaction data and evaluate the `require()` - so some gas got burned.

If gas is returned to the signer, it's the remaining gas. This is like filling your tank, then aborting your trip. You maybe burned some while the engine was running but you still have most of it.

If a lot of processing unfolds before the abortive operation that reverts everything, it's possible most of the gas was used up.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Cool analogies!

Comment: Thanks for good explanation! It's easy to understand! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

For each operation executed by EVM, it consumes some amount of gas. If any instruction causes transaction to fail, the execution is stopped and no more gas is used after that point.

> Is the gas fee is paid after all operations in the function which is in smart contract?

Gas is consumed at each step of transaction execution

> Then, if the require() function is placed at the start of the function and the codes aren't operated at all, there is no gas fee is needed?

Yes. If require causes the execution to stop, no more gas is consumed so no more gas is used after the execution of `require`.

> And what if the value is not valid in that require() statement condition and the transaction failed?

As covered in first statement, gas will be used at every step. And will continue till the instruction which causes transaction to fail. This is why it is preferred to know beforehand if the transaction fails or not. And to do this, these checks are placed in the beginning.

> Is the gas fee will be 100% refunded to caller or caller have to pay a remaining gas fee after some operations worked in the function?

Have to pay a remaining gas fee after some operations worked in the function

> The caller can be refunded all gas fee?

No. `require` also uses some gas, and that will not be refunded. It has been consumed.

> If the gas fee has to be paid after the code has been executed, what happens if caller(msg.sender) can not pay the gas fee because caller's account has no balance after the require () conditional pass?

```
gas fee = amount of gas* price of 1 gas
```

So *gas* is consumed. Blockchain client(geth/parity/...) will not accept the transaction in which `gasPrice*amountOfGas` exceeds the balance of the account. So we see that the gas price is paid when transaction gets submitted to the blockchain client.