# If a contract call fails at require is the ethereum value returned to msg sender?

Tags: solidity, ether, evm, msg.sender

According to [this](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/57477/86303) and [this](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/46829/86303) answer any remaining gas after a `require` statements `assert` condition fails is returned/refunded back to `msg.sender` but what about any ETHER sent in that transaction call i.e. `msg.value`? Is that also refunded/returned back to the user?

Answer (score 1):

Transfering ETH (which is done by setting `msg.value`) is a state change. When your transaction reverts any state change is also reverted. This means the value "stays" in the original wallet.

As you mentioned the only change that is done to the blockchain is the fee payment.

Note: If an internal transaction reverts, it doesn't mean that the whole Ethereum transaction reverted. The value transfer will only undone if the (internal) transaction related to that transfer is reverted.